# Python list sorting gives the wrong result

Tags: python, sorting

I want to sort a list in Python. What I've tried to do is:

```
activities = [[3,1,0,5,8,5],[4,2,6,7,9,9]]
activities.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
print(activities)
```

but it doesn't work.

I am expecting the lists to be sorted like this:

```
[1,3,0,5,8,5]
[2,4,6,7,9,9]
```

Comment: Are you expecting to modify the lists while sorting them?

Comment: How can i do this ? I am new in Python

Comment: Sort the lists and then modify them, or modify the lists and then sort them. Don't try to do both at once.

Comment: Do just want to sort the second list?

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to swap the first two elements of each sublist, and sort afterwards?

```
activities = [[3,1,0,5,8,5],[4,2,6,7,9,9]]
activities = [a[1::-1] + a[2:] for a in activities]
activities.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
print(activities)
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to sort the 2 sublists separately like so:

```
activities = [[3,1,0,5,8,5],[4,2,6,7,9,9]]
activities = activities[0].sort() 
activities = activities[1].sort() 
print(activities)
```